# VBA Excel - Addpicture set .left from center of picture and not from top left corner

Tags: excel, vba, image

I have a filepicker to select an image to load into an Excel sheet.
I did it with the addpicture option and setting a distance from top and left.
My height is constant at 55 pixels but my width changes depending on the picture.

So my problem here is that I can't set a fixed .left input as it counts from the top left corner. 
Is there a way to make the .left input count from the center of the image?

Extra info: The center of the picture will always be the center of the page, that might give an easier solution for the code.

I currently have the following code

```
Set xSh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Logopath, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, _
     Left:=250, Top:=308, Width:=-1, Height:=55)
```

I tried to get this done with fill.shapes before but there I failed to autosize the width of the shape according to the ratio. So if I can center or set .left from the center of the picture I'm done.

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzziB.png)

[Result answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNQhE.png)

Comment: Set `Left` to your page width halved, minus your picture width halved

Comment: picture width changes constantly. One time the picture could be 100 pixels wide and in another instance it could be 20 wide.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I thought you were trying to position your picture in the centre of the page, which my previous comment would do. It takes into account a variable picture width, as long as you input it into the calculation.

Comment: aah ok, my apologies I misunderstood your first comment.
Is it similar to the following?
`.Left = .TopLeftCell.Left + (.TopLeftCell.Width - .Width) / 2`
I tried this but this gives me errors

Comment: If you could include a screenshot in your question of how you'd like it to look, it would be helpful. Did you mean to say you want it in the middle of your screen, rather than in the middle of your page?

Comment: I added the picture in the main questions.
So this is a front page of a bunch of documents.
The picture is takes from a filepicker and loaded into the sheet.
It needs to be centered there were the selected shape is.
The picture will be limited to 55 height to fit in the white box but the width needs to change accordingly. 
Currently the picture is placed at the correct height but due to changing widths it's not centered with every logo I select.
The center of the logo should be the center of the page, if it turns out to be unaligned I can always edit the main page to align it

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to centre align the picture horizontally, leaving `.Top` unchanged:

```
xSh.Left = (ActiveWindow.UsableWidth - xSh.Width) / 2
```

Insert it after your existing code.

Comment: I edited the main question with the result of that code. 
Is there anything else for activewindow.usablewidth we can use?

Comment: Since your background picture doesn't fill the whole `UsableWidth`, replace `ActiveWindow.UsableWidth` with the width of your background picture.

Comment: I found the solution
`Set xSh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Logopath, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=0, Top:=308, Width:=-1, Height:=55)
      xSh.Left = (280 - (xSh.Width / 2))`

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my issue

```
Set xSh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Logopath, LinkToFile:=msoFalse, SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=0, Top:=308, Width:=-1, Height:=55)
  xSh.Left = (280 - (xSh.Width / 2))
```

Thanks to 0liveradam8 to getting me on the right track